# Paypal recurring payment with variable amount first month

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

First, notice I have read many post regarding this topic, but the info provided is not enough for me or is not accurate.

I´m developing a website with **ASP.Net Core** that offers different services. Users can subscribe to these services and they get a Paypal Recurring Payment to pay these services (using subscription API). For a fixed amount the service is working well for me.

Now thing is that i want to introduce a Discount system to user. When user apply some coupon code then some discount will be applicable only first month and rest of month user will pay full amount.

**Caes 1**

Suppose i have a service plan $200 per month. When a user purchase service and enter Coupon code XXXXXX then first month charges will be $150 and rest month $200 every month.

**Caes 2**

Suppose i have a service plan $200 per month. When a user purchase service and enter Coupon code YYYYYY then first month charges will be $130 and rest month $200 every month.

I have read many docs and but didn't find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Coupons are your own business. Have the user enter their coupons, calculate what you want to charge, and then create a plan for what you want to charge.

You can show your coupon negative amount discounts in the plan *text description* so the user sees them during checkout, and feels good about paying less. But as far as actual amounts for payment processing, PayPal doesn't care about that; it just needs to know the actual amounts that are being charged at each moment.

Comment: Any other way because if i have 1000 coupon then i will create 1000 plan.